# Configuring camera with uv4l

Tags: camera, uv4l, v4l2

I am using a USB camera and uv4l to stream the video to another machine. This is how I invoke uv4l: `uv4l --driver uvc --device-id [bus:id] --config-file /etc/uv4l/uv4l-uvc.conf`

I want to configure the camera exposure, resolution, brightness, etc. but I can't find a way to do it. Before installing uv4l I can use `v4l2-ctl` or `uvcdynctrl` to set the parameters. Now `v4l2-ctl` and `uvcdynctrl` both say that they can't find any devices. I'm using a Rpi 3 and Raspbian Stretch. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On my setup (stretch, pi zero, and pi camera via csi) I needed to say 
--device=/dev/video1 
to get v4l2-ctl to work